# selectOneListBox with size 1 appears as drop down menu

Tags: html, jsf, listbox, selectonemenu

I am using h:selectOneListBox to dynamically add data in it. Initially it is empty. Every time user presses on "Add" button,  an entry is added in list box.

I have specified particular height of list box. Issue is the appearance of listbox when it has only one entry. It appears like drop down menu of the specified height rather than list box. If it has more than one entry, it looks fine.

Need to know, if there is any way I can control the appearance of selectOneListBox when its size is 1. In below code, assume backingBean.names return only one select item.

```
<div style="height: 400px">
<h:selectOneListbox id="names" style="width:100%; height:100%; " 
  value="#{backingBean.selectedName}">
<f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.Names}" />
</h:selectOneListbox>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify the size to be 2 or larger, otherwise it will indeed default to the size of the available select items.

```
<c:set var="size" value="#{fn:length(backingBean.names)}" />
...
<h:selectOneListbox ... size="#{size gt 1 ? size : 2}">
```